# Get/Set in Object-Oriented JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, get, set

```
Counter = function ()
{
    var _count;

    _count = 0;

    this.AddCounter = function()
    {
        _count++;
    };

    this.Reset = function ()
    {
        _count = 10;
    };

    Object.defineProperty( Counter, 'Value', {
    get : function(){ return _count; },
    set : function(){ _count = Value; },
    configurable: true } );

}

Clock = function ()
{ 
    var second = new Counter();
    var minute = new Counter ();
    var hour = new Counter();

    this.Reset = function()
    {
        second.Reset();
        minute.Reset();
        hour.Reset();
    };

    this.Tick = function()
    {
        second.AddCounter();
        if (second.Value == 60)
        {
            second.Reset();
            minute.AddCounter();
            if (minute.Value == 60)
            {
                minute.Reset();
                hour.AddCounter();
            }
        }
    };

    this.ReadClock = function()
    {
        var sz = 0;
        var mz = 0;
        var hz = 0;

        if (second.Value == 9) 
        {sz = null;}
        if (minute.Value == 9) 
        {mz = null;}
        if (hour.Value == 9) 
        {hz = null;}

        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = ("" + hz + hour.Value + ":" + mz + minute.Value + ":" + sz +second.Value);
    };
}

function Init()
{
    var myClock = new Clock();
    myClock.Tick();
    myClock.ReadClock();
}

window.onload = Init;
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
0undefined:0undefined:0undefined
```

I think the issue is something to do with my Get/Set Property.

Also struggling to get the clock to tick, but that might be solvable once I put the `Tick()` function in a for loop.

Comment: `Value` is the property of `Counter` object, not its' instance's property. For `Value` to be the property of instance you need to add the same in `Counter.prototype`

Comment: `set : function(Value){ _count = Value; }, ` Like that?
EDIT: Someone deleted their comment, that was the answer to theirs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating the accessor property on the `Counter` constructor function (i.e. `Counter.Value`), not on the currently created instance:

```
function Counter() {
    var _count = 0;

    this.AddCounter = function() {
        _count++;
    };

    this.Reset = function() {
        _count = 10;
    };

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'Value', {
//                        ^^^^
        get: function(){ return _count; },
        set: function(val){ _count = val; },
        configurable: true
    });
}
```